# My raspberry pi 3 doesn't have the desktop screen everyone else has

Tags: pi-3, desktop

I have searched this problem up but can't find what I'm looking for. in books etc. it has the desktop installed but no information on how to get to that. Am I just a massive noob or is this a problem most people find

Comment: You've been really vague in what the problem is. For a start you haven't even specified what operating system you are using which does make a difference. You might find it useful to include a picture of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: i dont know what system i am using, but i turn it on, it loads and then gives me different categories and the apps i have on there. i can also only use the controller upon start up

Comment: what controller? As Darth Vader mentioned a picture would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention which distro you are using, but assuming you are at the Raspbian command prompt and looking to start the graphical desktop, you can switch to the desktop (GUI) mode by typing:

```
startx
```

If you want your Pi to always start in GUI mode. Begin by launching the configuration tool with the following command:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then select: **Boot Options**

Then **Desktop/CLI**

select one of the GUI options (i.e. with or without a password)

Then click **Ok**

Next click: **Finish**

and finally, reboot your Pi

Comment: I will definitely try this, when i get the chance, but i really appreciate that you  have the solution to my problem